# Ruby CSV::Row fetch(){block}, block not firing

Tags: ruby, csv, import

```
$ ruby -v; rails -v; grep DESCR /etc/lsb-release; psql --version 
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.0
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.5
```

I am iterating over a .csv file using `CSV.foreach(path, {headers: :first_row}) do |row|`.  One of the columns in my data is Yes/No-ish and I am converting it to `true`/`false` before my record gets created.  Right now, I'm using these two lines of code but they aren't quite elegant enough for me.  More alarmingly, they seem to point out I fundamentally don't understand how to properly use blocks in ruby.

Again, these work good enough:

```
temp = row.fetch("Header42") # { |something| could be processed here... }
column = (temp.nil? || !(temp.downcase.eql? "yes")) ? false : true
```

...but I'm looking do a little less.  I tried this and ended up with the un-translated string instead of the desired boolean:

```
column = row.fetch("Header42") { |r| (r.nil? || !(r.downcase.eql? "yes")) ? false : true }
```

When playing with `puts` in the block I can't seem to even get it to fire -- much less give me the value I expect for the assignment.

[I'm using this as my documentation for CSV::Row.fetch(){}](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-fetch).

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Row.fetch(header) grabs the field for the given header string. If the field doesn't exist, *then* the block is called, and the block is given the header string. The documentation actually says this, though it's admittedly a bit confusing. I had to read the source code before I understood.

[from CSV::Row.fetch:](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-fetch)

> if there is a field with the given header, its value is returned. Otherwise, if a block is given, it is yielded the header and its result is returned.

If you want to make your code eloquent *and* robust, try using the default parameter, which is returned when a header cannot be found:

```
column = (row.fetch("Header42", false)) && (temp.downcase == "yes")
```

If you don't expect headers not to be found, you can get away with:

```
column = row.fetch("Header42") && temp.downcase == "yes"
```

Comment: Thanks for this eiko -- I was clearly misunderstanding how to use the fetch block.  All of the lines in my file have something from the "yes/NO/Nil family"  so the default value never would never be used.  Additionally, though I've not used `tap` yet I think in this context the block would return true or false but the un-modified string object would be returned by `.tap{}`

Comment: Ah, well if you don't want to protect against missing rows then you can simplify even more: `column = row.fetch("Header42") && temp.downcase == "yes"` Though I prefer to expect the unexpected ^-^

And you are absolutely right about tap, my mistake! I guess you _can't_ always satisfy that one-liner craving using tap. I'll take that out of my answer.